# Regex: How to get filename without leading numbers?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm completely useless with regex in general with c-sharp: How can I parse away leading numbers in a filename? E.g. `413_somename.suffix`. I need: `_somename.suffix`.

How can I achieve this?

thx!

p.s.: Amount of numbers is one to n...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("^[0-9]*");
string s = rgx.Replace("413_somename.suffix", "");
```

Comment: @Barry - you are mostly correct, but in .Net `\d` also includes all Unicode digits.

Answer (score 4):

Is it always the same pattern? `number_somename.suffix`? Then imo RegEx is overkill and will only make things complicated.
Try this:

```
var s = "1234_somename.suffix";
var result = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("_"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Two non-regex options.

First, using [`TrimStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx):

```
filename = filename.TrimStart("0123456789".ToCharArray());
```

Another option using LINQ:

```
filename = String.Concat(filename.SkipWhile(Char.IsDigit));
```

Comment: hmm, I like the linq-version, but it doesn't work with SkipWhile as you posted it...

Comment: @sl3dg3 - Are you using .Net 3.5? If so, you need `filename = new String(filename.SkipWhile(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());`. Also, can you please specify how it "doesn't work"? I did test both options after posting.

Comment: sorry, I was wrong. I forgot that I am using VB here... ;-)  VB and Linq is not such a nice thing when it comes to the syntax, IMO.